# How to detect edges swipe on android phone for manipulating touch behaviour?

Tags: android, android-gesture

I am implementing `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` in Activity,
whose overridden onTouchEvent is :

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
       //gestureDetector is new GestureDetector(this,this) in Activity's onCreate()
       this.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
       return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Using getEdgeFlags from MotionEvent Class for edge detection as follows:

```
 @Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    final int edgeInfo = e.getEdgeFlags();
    return ((edgeInfo == MotionEvent.EDGE_LEFT) || (edgeInfo == MotionEvent.EDGE_RIGHT)) ||
            (edgeInfo == MotionEvent.EDGE_BOTTOM);
}
```

But onDown always returns false.
I have also tried changing

`final int edgeInfo = e.getEdgeFlags();`   to
`final int edgeInfo = e.getAction() & e.getEdgeFlags();`

and also to `final int edgeInfo = e.getActionMasked() & e.getEdgeFlags();` in case.

But to avail no benefit.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167006/getedgeflags-always-returning-0) and [this one, more relevant to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955122/why-getedgeflags-always-return-0) but I found that only

1. Only some older phones return non zero value
2. I should do it myself.

> Am I Using API wrong?
>
> Is there a better alternative to getEdgeFlags()?
>
> Even if onDown is returning false,in logcat, I can still see other methods of `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` getting fired,Why?

*A little snippet would help if any.*